# How do I LDAP authenticate a self-hosted gitlab instance using AD Security Groups?

Tags: gitlab

The canonical name within AD is: `foo.com/zz-yyy/IT/zz-yyy-gitlab-users`
In my gitlab.rb file I have the below:

```
### LDAP Settings
###! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap/index.html
###! **Be careful not to break the indentation in the ldap_servers block. It is
###!   in yaml format and the spaces must be retained. Using tabs will not work.**

 gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
# gitlab_rails['prevent_ldap_sign_in'] = false

##! **remember to close this block with 'EOS' below**
 gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS'
   main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
     label: 'LDAP'
     host: 'foo.com'
     port: 389
     uid: 'sAMAccountName'
     bind_dn: 'gitlab@foo.com'
     password: 'changemeplease'
     encryption: 'plain' # "start_tls" or "simple_tls" or "plain"
     verify_certificates: true
     smartcard_auth: false
     active_directory: true
     allow_username_or_email_login: false
     lowercase_usernames: false
     block_auto_created_users: false
     base: 'OU=IT,OU=zz-yyy,DC=foo,DC=com'
#     user_filter: '(&(objectClass=user))'
#     ## EE only
#     group_base: ''
#     admin_group: ''
#     sync_ssh_keys: false
#
 EOS
```

After I reconfigure and run `gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check` all children within the IT, including other groups show up:

```
Checking LDAP ...

LDAP: ... Server: ldapmain
LDAP authentication... Success
LDAP users with access to your GitLab server (only showing the first 100 results)
        DN: cn=zz-yyy-gitlab-users,ou=it,ou=zz-yyy,dc=foo,dc=com   sAMAccountName: zz-   yyy-gitlab-users
        DN: cn=zz-yyy-gitlab-admins,ou=it,ou=zz-yyy,dc=foo,dc=com  sAMAccountName: zz-  yyy-gitlab-admins
        DN: cn=foo gitlab,ou=it,ou=zz-yyy,dc=foo,dc=com sAMAccountName: foo-gitlab
        DN: cn=jonathan weinraub,ou=it,ou=zz-yyy,dc=foo,dc=com  sAMAccountName:     jweinraub

Checking LDAP ... Finished
```

My issue is, how do I only get what is in the gitlab-users security group?
Also it is just the username that works, not email (userPrincipalName), is it possible to do both?

When I try to use CN=gitlab-users or whatever it shows nothing.
Though on the shell I can do:

`$ ldapsearch -x -W -D "gitlab@foo.com" -b "CN=zz-yyy-gitlab-users,OU=IT,OU=zz-yyy,DC=foo,DC=com" -H ldap://foo.com` and I get the proper results.

Thank you for any help.